# Problems with BigQuery not respecting WHEN statements

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following (subsection) of a query were I try to parse and correct certain dates from a string structure, were 9999 refers to a cyclic date and 9996 to cyclic date only valid for leap years.

The FIX_YEAR function which changes the 9999 year to the current cycle should ignore any 9996 year input, but when I ran the query with the example string it's not being ignores.

---

Any ideas what the issue could be?

Thanks!

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION
  FIX_YEAR(val STRUCT<after DATE,
    before DATE>) AS (
    CASE
      WHEN (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM val.after) = 9999) AND (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM val.before) = 9999) THEN ( CASE
        WHEN DATE(EXTRACT(YEAR
        FROM
          CURRENT_DATE), EXTRACT(MONTH
        FROM
          val.after), EXTRACT(DAY
        FROM
          val.after)) <= DATE(EXTRACT(YEAR
        FROM
          CURRENT_DATE), EXTRACT(MONTH
        FROM
          val.before), EXTRACT(DAY
        FROM
          val.before)) THEN (
        CASE
          WHEN DATE(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE), EXTRACT(MONTH FROM val.before), EXTRACT(DAY FROM val.before)) < CURRENT_DATE THEN ( [STRUCT ( DATE(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE) + 1, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM val.after), EXTRACT(DAY FROM val.after)) AS after, DATE(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE) + 1, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM val.before), EXTRACT(DAY FROM val.before)) AS before )] )
          WHEN DATE_DIFF( DATE(EXTRACT(YEAR
            FROM
              CURRENT_DATE) + 1, EXTRACT(MONTH
            FROM
              val.after), EXTRACT(DAY
            FROM
              val.after)), CURRENT_DATE, DAY) <= 330 THEN ( [STRUCT ( DATE(EXTRACT(YEAR
              FROM
                CURRENT_DATE) + 1, EXTRACT(MONTH
              FROM
                val.after), EXTRACT(DAY
              FROM
                val.after)) AS after,
            DATE(EXTRACT(YEAR
              FROM
                CURRENT_DATE) + 1, EXTRACT(MONTH
              FROM
                val.before), EXTRACT(DAY
              FROM
                val.before)) AS before ),
          STRUCT ( DATE(EXTRACT(YEAR
              FROM
                CURRENT_DATE), EXTRACT(MONTH
              FROM
                val.after), EXTRACT(DAY
              FROM
                val.after)) AS after,
            DATE(EXTRACT(YEAR
              FROM
                CURRENT_DATE), EXTRACT(MONTH
              FROM
                val.before), EXTRACT(DAY
              FROM
                val.before)) AS before )] )
        ELSE
        ( [STRUCT ( DATE(EXTRACT(YEAR
              FROM
                CURRENT_DATE), EXTRACT(MONTH
              FROM
                val.after), EXTRACT(DAY
              FROM
                val.after)) AS after,
            DATE(EXTRACT(YEAR
              FROM
                CURRENT_DATE), EXTRACT(MONTH
              FROM
                val.before), EXTRACT(DAY
              FROM
                val.before)) AS before )] )
      END
        )
      ELSE
      [val]
    END
      )
    ELSE
    [val]
  END
    );
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION
  EXTRACT_SEASONAL_DATES(season_text STRING) AS ( FIX_YEAR ( STRUCT ( PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d',
          COALESCE(REGEXP_EXTRACT(season_text, r'^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})@'),
            '9999-12-31')) AS after,
        PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d',
          COALESCE(REGEXP_EXTRACT(season_text, r'@(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})$'),
            '9999-12-31')) AS before ) ) );
SELECT
  EXTRACT_SEASONAL_DATES(season_inbound) season_inbound
FROM (
  SELECT
    "9999-02-01@9999-02-02,9999-02-09@9999-02-09,9999-02-15@9999-02-17,9999-02-22@9999-02-24,9996-02-29@9999-03-02,9999-04-08@9999-04-13,9999-05-03@9999-05-04,9999-05-24@9999-05-25,9999-07-01@9999-07-06,9999-07-15@9999-07-17,9999-07-19@9999-07-20,9999-07-24@9999-07-29,9999-08-16@9999-08-17,9999-09-12@9999-09-23,9999-11-02@9999-11-02" AS season_inbound)
CROSS JOIN
  UNNEST(SPLIT(season_inbound, ',')) season_inbound
```

Comment: tried to run it, got an error `Input calculates to invalid date: 2019-02-29` - that's the problem?

Comment: what you mean by "should ignore any 9996 year input"? should it leave as is or should respective row  be excluded from output? please clarify

Comment: Interesting, I didn't have chance to run/test your original query - but did run the one that is edited by Ben P - and it worked as expected meaning `9996-02-29` was ignored and not processed  - thus not generated error. meantime - when i tried to refactor that query to something more readable - the error about invalid date was raised

Comment: while it was easy to fix the query - so far I am giving up on explaining such a strange behavior - based on documentation first when expression that is evaluated to tru is being processed and the rest ignored  - so sure that error makes no sense to me - might be a bug to report? not sure :o(

Comment: I tried the query syntax highlighted by Ben P, but didn't get the same result as @MikhailBerlyant I always get the same `Input calculates to invalid date: 2019-02-29`

Answer (score 1):

I think that the code is working fine.

As @FelipeHoffa mentioned in the firs comment  the issue is related with  an error with an invalid date, for  your case "9996-02-29@9999-03-02", this is an invalid date since  your function transforms it into "2019-02-29" that date doesn't exist, for that reason BigQuery throws the error message "Input calculates to invalid date: 2019-02-29".

I have modified this date to "9996-02-28@9999-03-02" and all works fine.

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION
  FIX_YEAR(val STRUCT<after DATE,
    before DATE>) AS (
    CASE
      WHEN (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM val.after) = 9999) AND (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM val.before) = 9999) THEN ( CASE
        WHEN DATE(EXTRACT(YEAR
        FROM
          CURRENT_DATE), EXTRACT(MONTH
        FROM
          val.after), EXTRACT(DAY
        FROM
          val.after)) <= DATE(EXTRACT(YEAR
        FROM
          CURRENT_DATE), EXTRACT(MONTH
        FROM
          val.before), EXTRACT(DAY
        FROM
          val.before)) THEN (
        CASE
          WHEN DATE(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE), EXTRACT(MONTH FROM val.before), EXTRACT(DAY FROM val.before)) < CURRENT_DATE THEN ( [STRUCT ( DATE(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE) + 1, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM val.after), EXTRACT(DAY FROM val.after)) AS after, DATE(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE) + 1, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM val.before), EXTRACT(DAY FROM val.before)) AS before )] )
          WHEN DATE_DIFF( DATE(EXTRACT(YEAR
            FROM
              CURRENT_DATE) + 1, EXTRACT(MONTH
            FROM
              val.after), EXTRACT(DAY
            FROM
              val.after)), CURRENT_DATE, DAY) <= 330 THEN ( [STRUCT ( DATE(EXTRACT(YEAR
              FROM
                CURRENT_DATE) + 1, EXTRACT(MONTH
              FROM
                val.after), EXTRACT(DAY
              FROM
                val.after)) AS after,
            DATE(EXTRACT(YEAR
              FROM
                CURRENT_DATE) + 1, EXTRACT(MONTH
              FROM
                val.before), EXTRACT(DAY
              FROM
                val.before)) AS before ),
          STRUCT ( DATE(EXTRACT(YEAR
              FROM
                CURRENT_DATE), EXTRACT(MONTH
              FROM
                val.after), EXTRACT(DAY
              FROM
                val.after)) AS after,
            DATE(EXTRACT(YEAR
              FROM
                CURRENT_DATE), EXTRACT(MONTH
              FROM
                val.before), EXTRACT(DAY
              FROM
                val.before)) AS before )] )
        ELSE
        ( [STRUCT ( DATE(EXTRACT(YEAR
              FROM
                CURRENT_DATE), EXTRACT(MONTH
              FROM
                val.after), EXTRACT(DAY
              FROM
                val.after)) AS after,
            DATE(EXTRACT(YEAR
              FROM
                CURRENT_DATE), EXTRACT(MONTH
              FROM
                val.before), EXTRACT(DAY
              FROM
                val.before)) AS before )] )
      END
        )
      ELSE
      [val]
    END
      )
    ELSE
    [val]
  END
    );
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION
  EXTRACT_SEASONAL_DATES(season_text STRING) AS ( FIX_YEAR ( STRUCT ( PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d',
          COALESCE(REGEXP_EXTRACT(season_text, r'^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})@'),
            '9999-12-31')) AS after,
        PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d',
          COALESCE(REGEXP_EXTRACT(season_text, r'@(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})$'),
            '9999-12-31')) AS before ) ) );
SELECT
  EXTRACT_SEASONAL_DATES(season_inbound) season_inbound
FROM (
  SELECT
    "9999-02-01@9999-02-02,9999-02-09@9999-02-09,9999-02-15@9999-02-17,9999-02-22@9999-02-24,9996-02-28@9999-03-02,9999-04-08@9999-04-13,9999-05-03@9999-05-04,9999-05-24@9999-05-25,9999-07-01@9999-07-06,9999-07-15@9999-07-17,9999-07-19@9999-07-20,9999-07-24@9999-07-29,9999-08-16@9999-08-17,9999-09-12@9999-09-23,9999-11-02@9999-11-02" AS season_inbound)
CROSS JOIN
  UNNEST(SPLIT(season_inbound, ',')) season_inbound
```

Getting this results:

[image]

Comment: The problem I find is that a date 9996-02-29 shouldn't be evaluated and should be ignored (because of the 9999 filter). The 9996-02-29 are processed on a different UDF

Comment: The error consists on throwing an invalid date error of february 29th, when the february 29th only comes in 9996-02-29 format which should be excluded on the first WHEN

Comment: The issue is that when you used the date "9996-02-29" it is first evaluated by EXTRACT_SEASONAL_DATES, and it never reach FIX_YEAR because  "9996-02-29" is not a valid date, for that reason when using  "9996-02-28" FIX_YEAR shows you the  date without conversion.

Comment: Thanks! That would be true, but 9996-02-29 is indeed a leap year, so it should be a valid date. The problem then must be on the PARSE_DATE function

Comment: and also the error it shows is 2021-02-29, so it is using the FIX_YEAR function